# Add VBO checkbox to send Bulk emails in Admin

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, views

We are using Enterprise Event module in Drupal 7.  I checked the Views and module files but not able to locate the file as from where Manage Registration Page is formed. Please guide me how I can add VBO checkbox to send Bulk emails in Admin > Content > Event > Edit > Manage Registration Tab.

I am using enterprise event module in which people register for upcoming events. Registration module is used for registration. Admin can view registrants for  specific event.  I need to add a checkbox so that admin can send bulk emails to those registrants.

[image: add VBO checkbox to send Bulk emails in Admin] 
Please help still hoping for some solution.

Comment: question is not clear for those that have not used enterprise event module before. So you just want to know how to use the vbo module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

- Go to *Structure* > *Views* and locate the *Test Event* view.
- Click the *Edit* button.
- Find the *Fields* display and click the *Add* button.

[image: fields display add button]

- Filter the available fields by *Bulk Operations* and select a field you need, e.g. *Bulk Operations: User*.

[image: bulk operations field user]

- Now the settings for this field show up. Scroll down to *Selected Bulk Operations* and select *Send Email*.

[image: bulk operation send email]

- Click Apply.
- Don't forget to save your view.
- Now you should have a checkbox and you can select *Send Email* from a drop down menu.

I'd personaly would not use the VBO field but the [Views Send](http://drupal.org/project/views_send) module which is a bit easier to use. If you have the *Views Send* module, add the field *Global: Send Email* instead of the VBO field and proceed as described above.